# LINQ Joining Two Tables and Getting the Row with Max ID

Tags: c#, linq

I need to join two tables, getting the latest row (one with Maximum ID on one table).

I have the following tables (and sample data):

**tblParts**

```
PartID
1
2
3
```

**tblPartsVersion**

```
PartVersionID PartID Name
1             1      Hammer v1
2             1      Hammer v2
3             1      Hammer v3
4             2      Screw V1
5             2      Screw V2
6             3      Nail V1
```

I have already constructed the SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT a.PartVersionID, a.Name
FROM tblPartsVersion a
JOIN tblParts b ON b.PartID = a.PartID
LEFT JOIN tblPartsVersion c ON c.PartID = a.PartID
AND c.PartVersionID > a.PartVersionID
WHERE c.PartVersionID IS NULL
```

Pretty much, I am getting the results I need:

```
PartVersionID Name
3             Hammer V3
5             Screw V2
6             Nail V1
```

I need some help trying to convert this query to LINQ, and I am getting stumped writing the proper code for it.

My LINQ query at the moment is as follows:

```
var qry = (from a in tblParts
           join b in tblPartsVersion ON a.PartID equals b.PartID
select b).ToList()
```

Essentially, from my LINQ query, I need to add the other join or where clause conditions, but I don't have any idea how.

Looking for some tips and help. Thanks.

**Update:**

I've re-written my query as follows and it seems to be retrieving the records as I required:

```
var qry1 = from a in tblPartsVersion
           group a by a.PartID into grp
           select new {MaxID = grp.Max(x => x.PartVersionID), grp.Key };

var qry2 = (from q1 in qry1
            join b in tblPartsVersion on q1.MaxID equals b.PartVersionID
            join c in tblParts on b.PartID equals c.PartID
            select b).ToList();
```

I am wondering if this is the best way to do it? I tried different variations of the data, and this query seems to work out fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reason to reference the Part table at all unless there exists part versions that don't exist in parts, and you aren't returning anything from that table, so it makes the query that much easier (and faster):

```
var currentParts=tblPartsVersion
  .GroupBy(v=>v.PartID)
  .Select(x=>x.OrderByDescending(pv=>pv.PartVersionID).First());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the latest version of each part. In order to do that, you can group them by `PartID` and keep only the one with the highest `PartVersionID`.

The `Join` seems unnecessary here, unless you need to filter out parts that exists in `tblPartsVersion`, but not in `tblParts`.

```
var latestParts = tblPartsVersion
    .Join(tblParts, version => version.PartID, part => part.PartID, (v, p) => v)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.PartVersionID)
    .GroupBy(x => x.PartID)
    // if this still doesn't work, uncomment the next line
    //.AsEnumerable() //this will pull entire tblPartsVersion from db
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: Got an error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'tblPartsVersion Last[tblPartsVersion]' method and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need filter this query using lambda expressions.

Like:

```
var query = (from a in tblParts
             join b in tblPartsVersion on a.PartID equals b.PartID
             select b)
              .GroupBy( c => c.PartID)
              .Select( d => d.LastOrDefault()).ToList();
```